# How to show these two definitions of the Riemann integral are equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Let $P=\{a=t_0<t_1<\cdots<t_n=b\}$ be partition of $[a,b]$

$P^*=(P,\xi)$ , $\xi=(\xi_1,\xi_2,\cdots,\xi_n)$ , $t_{i-1}\le\xi_i \le t_i$

We define $\displaystyle \sum (f,P^*)=\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(\xi_i) \cdot (t_i-t_{i-1}) $

$||P||=\underset {1\le i\le n}{\text{max}} (t_i-t_{i-1})$

---

**Definition $1$**

We define $\displaystyle \int_a^b f =\lim_{||P||\to0} \sum(f,P^*)$ if the limit exists

$\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists\delta>0: \forall P^* ,||P||<\delta \Longrightarrow \left|\displaystyle \int_a^b f-\sum(f,P^*)\right|<\epsilon$

---

**Definition $2$**

Another definition of Riemann integral:

If there is a number $L$ such that:

$\forall \epsilon >0 , \exists P_{\epsilon} $ partition of $[a,b]: \forall P^*=(P,\xi) ,  P_{\epsilon}\subset P $ finer partition $ \Longrightarrow |L-\sum(f,P^*)|<\epsilon$

then $\displaystyle \int_a^b f=L$

---

We note that Definition $1$ implies Definition $2$, but what about the converse ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Oh, you wrote "Riemann Stieltjes" and I was misled to believe you wanted to prove it fails in the general case. Yes, for the usual Riemann integral they are equivalent. Maybe you can make this clearer?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: What does $\lim_{\lVert P \rVert\to 0}$ mean, exactly? It is not very easy to define such a thing in a rigorous way. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53001/8157)

Comment: Why does definition 1 imply definition 2?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a sketch presented in Apostol's Mathematical Analysis. Can you fill in the details? There aren't too many left! You need to look at the $S_1,S_2$ carefully.

> Let $\int_a^b f(x)dx =I$, $M=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in[a,b]\}$. Given $\epsilon >0$; choose $P_\epsilon$ such that $U(P_\epsilon,f)<I+\dfrac \epsilon 2$. [Here $U$ is the upper Darboux/Riemann sum of $f$] Let $N$ be the number of points of division in $P_\epsilon$ and let $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2MN}$. If $\Vert P\Vert <\delta$ put $$U(f,P)=\sum M_kf(x) \Delta_x=S_1+S_2$$ where $S_1$ is the sum over the terms that belong to the subintervals of $P$ that have no points of $P_\epsilon$ and $S_2$ is the remianing sum. Then $$S_1\leq U(P_\epsilon,f)<I+\frac \epsilon 2$$ $$S_2\leq NM\Vert P\Vert <NM\delta=\frac\epsilon 2$$ thus $$U(P,f)<I+\epsilon$$ Analogously, $$L(f,P)>I-\epsilon$$ if $\Vert P\Vert<\delta^\prime$, for a suitable $\delta^\prime$. Thus $$|S(P,f)-I|<\epsilon$$ if $\Vert P\Vert<\min\{\delta,\delta^{\prime}\}$.

**NOTATION** $U(f,P)$ denotes the upper sum of $f$ w.r.t $P$, that is $$\sum M_k \Delta x_k$$ where $M_i$ is the supremum of $f$ over the $i$-th  subinterval of $P$. Analogously, $L(f,P)$ is the lower sum of $f$ w.r.t. $P$. Finally $S(f,P)$ is any Riemann sum of a tagged partition $P$.

Comment: But in this case $\alpha(t)=t$ , $\forall t \in [a,b]$  $\displaystyle \int_a^b f d \alpha = \int_a^b f$

Comment: But the question is whether the Definition $2$ implies Definition $1$ if $\alpha(t)=t$ , $\forall t \in [a,b]$

Comment: @felipeuni Oh, you wrote "Riemann Stieltjes" and I was misled to believe you wanted to prove it fails in the general case. Yes, for the usual Riemann integral they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks Peter Tamaroff for your explanation.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Which page in Apostol's can I find this?

Comment: @Heisenberg this is exercise 7.4 there.

Answer (score 6):

When proving that a function which is integrable according Definition 2 is also integrable according to Definition 1, given $\epsilon\gt 0$ one is tempted to take $\delta$ as $\Vert P_\epsilon\Vert$. The problem is that there can be partitions $P$ with $\Vert P\Vert \lt \delta$ but $P\not\supseteq P_\epsilon$. So, how will we use Definition 2 then? Let's see.

We say that $f\in \mathscr R[a,b]$ when $f$ is integrable according to Definition 2. We also write $\mathscr P[a,b]$ for the set of partitions of the interval $[a,b]$. As usual $\Vert f\Vert_\infty =\sup\{|f(x)| : x\in [a,b]\}$.

**Lemma** *Let $f:[a,b]\to \Bbb R$ be a bounded function, and $P\in \mathscr P[a,b]$.*

1. *If $P_1$ is the partition obtained from $P$ by adding one point then*
   \begin{gather*}
   L(P_1,f)\leq L(P,f) + 2\Vert f\Vert_\infty \Vert P\Vert\\
   U(P_1,f)\geq U(P,f) - 2\Vert f\Vert_\infty \Vert P\Vert
   \end{gather*}
2. *If $P_m$ is the partition obtained from $P$ by adding $m$ points then*
   \begin{gather*}
   L(P_m,f)\leq L(P,f) + 2m\Vert f\Vert_\infty \Vert P\Vert\\
   U(P_m,f)\geq U(P,f) - 2m\Vert f\Vert_\infty \Vert P\Vert
   \end{gather*}

*Proof.*

1. Let $z\in [a,b]$ be the point to be added. If $P = \{a=x_0,x_1\ldots,x_n=b\}$, there is some $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ so that $z\in [x_{k-1},x_k]$. Thus, letting
   \begin{gather*}
   m^\prime = \inf f\left(\left[x_{k-1},z\right]\right)\\
   m^{\prime\prime} = \inf f\left(\left[z,x_k\right]\right)
   \end{gather*}
   we have
   \begin{align*}
   L(P,f) - L(P_1,f)
   &= m_k(f)\left(x_k - x_{k-1}\right) - m^\prime\left(z - x_{k-1}\right) - m^{\prime\prime}\left(x_k - z\right)\\
   &\leq \Vert f\Vert_\infty\left(x_k - x_{k-1}\right) + \Vert f\Vert_\infty\left(z - x_{k-1}\right) + \Vert f\Vert_\infty\left(x_k - z\right)\\
   &= 2\Vert f\Vert_\infty\left( x_k - x_{k-1}\right)\\
   &\leq 2\Vert f\Vert_\infty\Vert P\Vert.
   \end{align*}
   The other inequality is similar.
2. This follows by adding one point at time and iterating the inequalities in 1.

Now, suppose $f\in \mathscr R[a,b]$. Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. Then we know that
$$
\underline{\int_a^b} f(x)\mathrm d x = \int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x = 
\overline{\int_a^b} f(x)\mathrm d x,
$$
so by properties of sup (and inf), there exist $P_1,P_2\in\mathscr P[a,b]$ such that if $P\in\mathscr P[a,b]$ with $P\supseteq P_1$ ($P\supseteq P_2$) then 
\begin{gather*}
\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x - \frac\epsilon 2 \lt L\left(P_1,f\right)\\
\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x + \frac\epsilon 2 \gt U\left(P_2,f\right).
\end{gather*}
Let
$$
P=P_1\cup P_2 = \{x_0,\ldots,x_n\}
$$
and $\delta = \frac\epsilon {4n\Vert f\Vert_\infty}$. Let $Q$ be a partition of $[a,b]$, with $\Vert Q\Vert\lt \delta$. Then $P\cup Q$ is obtained from $Q$ by adding at most $n-1$ points. Remember that when you add points to a partition, lower sums increases and upper sums decreases, thus
\begin{gather*}
\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x -\frac\epsilon 2 \lt L(P_1,f)\leq L(P\cup Q,f) \leq L(Q,f) + 2(n-1)\Vert f\Vert_\infty\Vert Q\Vert.\\
\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x -\frac\epsilon 2 \lt L(Q,f) + 2(n-1)\Vert f\Vert_\infty \frac\epsilon{4n\Vert f\Vert_\infty}\\
\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x -\frac\epsilon 2 \lt L(Q,f) + \frac\epsilon 2 \\
\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x -\frac\epsilon 2 \lt \sum (Q^\ast,f) + \frac\epsilon 2\\
\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x \lt \sum(Q^\ast,f) + \epsilon.
\end{gather*}
Similarly, using upper sums we get
$$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x \gt \sum(Q^\ast,f) - \epsilon.$$
Therefore $$\left| \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm d x - \sum(Q^\ast,f)\right|\lt \epsilon,$$
whenever $\Vert Q\Vert\lt\delta$, that is, $f$ is integrable according to Definition 1.

**Notes** This approach was found as Exercise 19 in Section 7.1 of the Spanish translation of *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert Bartle and Donald Shertbert. It was the second edition. Once I searched for that exercise in the newest edition. I couldn't fInd it. So Here it is.

Comment: You may be interested in a proposal for Math SE in Spanish:http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64529/matematicas-mathematics-se-in-spanish

Comment: @BrianRushton Indeed, thanks