# Why is the following claim true in Exercise 7.4, Apostol's Mathematical Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, definition, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

On [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408050/how-to-show-these-two-definitions-of-the-riemann-integral-are-equivalent/408113#408113?newreg=3e512d7ac4744ed5aabd8cf880f21869) page, a proof of the equivalence of two definitions of Riemann integrals is given by the user Pedro using Apostol's Hint for Exercise 7.4, Mathematical Analysis. However, I still find this claim unclear (particularly, the first inequality):

$$S_1\leq U(P_\epsilon,f)<I+\frac \epsilon 2$$

To me, it seems that this is true only if f(x)>=0 on [a,b]. I'm sure I must be missing a subtle point here, so I would really appreciate it if anyone could clarify this for me.

Comment: Put your LaTeX between \$\$...\$\$ in order to get it to render.

Comment: What is $S_1$? [didn't see on link]

Comment: It's in Pedro's answer, not in the original question.

Comment: The argument should be made for $U(P_\epsilon, f) - L(P_{\epsilon}, f) $ where the terms are non-negative. See details at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1834341/72031

Comment: Dealing with just upper (or lower sum) is tricky because of sign of terms and I have discussed that in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2047959/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks so much for your answers! They certainly clarify a lot.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Also, one more minor point to clarify. You chose $\delta = \epsilon / (2MN).$ However, there are $N$ partition points in $P_\epsilon,$ and at most, 2 partition intervals of $P$ containing each point in $P_\epsilon$ (since partition points of $P_\epsilon$ can lie on the end points of the closed sub-intervals corresponding to partition $P$). Therefore, shouldn't we have chosen $\delta = \epsilon / (4MN),$ instead?